# sql multiple tables into json with nested arrays

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table with hotel data, each row has an hotel id.
in 2 more tables (hotel images + hotel facilities) there are multiple lines corresponding to each single row in the main table (based on the hotel id value).

I am trying to join multiple tables into a json result.

the wanted outcome is:

```
     "{
        "hotels" : [
           {
             "ID": 1,
             "name": "hotelA",
             "star_rating": 5,
             "Address": "a",
             "isRefundable": true,
             "images":[
              {"url":"x", "title":"a", "description":"a"},
              {"url":"x", "title":"b", "description":"b"},
              {"url":"x", "title":"c", "description":"c"},
              {"url":"x", "title":"d", "description":"d"},
             ],
             "facilities":[
              {"facilityID": 1, "facilityName":"free wifi"},
              {"facilityID": 2, "facilityName":"free breakfast"},
              {"facilityID": 3, "facilityName":"TV"},
             ]
           },
           {...},{...},{...}
       ]}"
```

currently I've implemented this via code, **is there a way to do this using an sql procedure?** im using (microsoft sql)

im adding my schema underneath

Main Table (Hotel Table):

| ID | name | star_rating | Address | isRefundable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | hotelA | 5 | a | true |
| 2 | hotelB | 5 | b | true |
| 3 | hotelC | 3 | c | true |
| 4 | hotelD | 4 | d | true |
| 5 | hotelE | 5 | e | false |

Images Table:

| HotelID | url | title | description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | x | a | a |
| 1 | x | b | b |
| 1 | x | c | c |
| 1 | x | d | d |
| 2 | x | a | a |
| 2 | x | b | b |
| 2 | x | c | c |
| 3 | x | a | a |
| 3 | x | b | b |
| 4 | x | a | a |
| 5 | x | b | b |

Facilities Table:

| HotelID | facilityID | facilityName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | free wifi |
| 1 | 2 | free breakfast |
| 1 | 3 | TV |
| 3 | 1 | free wifi |
| 3 | 3 | TV |
| 5 | 4 | MiniFridge |

I have tried the following but it did not get me very far, because it did not handle multiple lines matching a single line between tables, so h got just one image/facility per hotel - and not all of the related rows.

```
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT hotel.*, facility.FacilityId, facility.FacilityName, img.url, img.title, img.description,
FROM [main_hotel_table] hotel
JOIN db.facilityTable facility ON hotel.HotelId = facility.HotelId
JOIN db.ImageTable img ON hotel.HotelId = img.HotelId

FOR JSON Path, ROOT('hotels')

END
```

**is there a way to do this using an sql procedure?**

Comment: The trick is to use nested json as columns. Something like: select field1, field2, (select field3, field4 from anothertable t where t.id = j.id for json path) from table j for json path

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

You must try something like this:

```sql
select hotel.*, 
(select facility.FacilityId, facility.FacilityName from #facilityTable facility where facility.HotelID=hotel.ID for json auto) facilities,
(select img.url, img.title, img.description from #ImageTable img where img.HotelID =hotel.ID for json auto) images
from #main_hotel_table hotel for json auto
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).